# using PuTTY to connect to telnet on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, putty

I'm trying to use telnet on my laptop running windows 8.1 x64 pro. I have tried connecting to it using telnet via command prompt and it hasn't worked. I've tried using PuTTY also and I can't get it to connect. All the tutorials I've found only tell me how to install it. If someone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are there firewall rules blocking it? If using SSH, a port such as 21 may need to be unblocked on the network.

Comment: If your goal is to use a remote Windows terminal, then telnet really isn't very good for this. If you'd like a Windows based SSH server then check this page out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers If you are connecting from Windows to another Windows machine then you can just use psExec: http://blogs.technet.com/b/systemcenteressentials/archive/2009/09/01/using-psexec-to-open-a-remote-command-window.aspx

Comment: So, you're running a telnet server right?  Which server are you running and how have you configured it (which port is it listening on)?

Comment: From a command prompt, from the directory where PuTTY.exe is at: `PuTTY -telnet hostname`

Answer (score 1):

1st of all:

If you want to connect to your laptop, you are from another computer.
So: computer A (Laptop)
and: Computer B(OtherComputer with Putty).

### If ComputerA and ComputerB are in the same network

,

In computerA: Get IP from computerA: Use 'ipconfig' command in a cmd command prompt. Go to computerB: make a pathping "IPComputerA".

make a "telnet IPComputerA 23"

If you don't get any response go to ComputerA and run in a command prompt: 
(Create 2 rules to open port 23 TCP and UDP): 

 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Telnet Port 23UDP" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=23 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Telnet Port 23TCP" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=23

you should be able to connect using credentials

### ComputerA and computerB are in public networks

Get the Public IP from computerA, using http://www.whatismyip.com/

From ComputerB, use: Telnet IPComputerA 23 and see if you have answer

If you don't get any response go to ComputerA and run in a command prompt: 
(Create 2 rules to open port 23 TCP and UDP): 

 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Telnet Port 23UDP" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=23 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Telnet Port 23TCP" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=23

Make the test again 
From ComputerB, use: Telnet IPComputerA 23 and see if you have answer

If you don't get any response. You need to check ComputerB (Default Gateway if port 23 is blocked).
Do the same for ComputerA.

When you get all ports open in all intermediates Routers (internet routers) you will be able to connect via telnet

Answer (score -1):

Need to check these things:

<del>- Putty will need to be run with Administrator privileges. this is because you are trying to use a privileged port (a port # between 0 and 1024)</del>

- Check that the firewall is not blocking port 23 (telnet default) or if using ssh (port 22).
- If it is highly likely that your anti virus has an integrated application firewall that is blocking this traffic as well.

If you don't know how to get Windows Firewall to allow a port (especially true for ports between 0 and 1024), you can look at [how to allow ftp traffic through windows 8 8-1 windows 7 firewall](http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-allow-ftp-traffic-through-windows-8-8-1-windows-7-firewall). Inbound rule is for traffic coming to the computer, outbound from the computer you are on to another.

- If you are running the Telnet server on the laptop, make sure it has the permission to run on the Telnet or SSH port

Comment: PuTTY does not need to be run with Administrator privileges, you only need to do that if you're listening on the privileged port, not connected to one, which since PuTTY is a telnet client, it would only be connecting to a server listening on port 23.

Comment: In his description, he said he is trying to connect to 'it' via telnet. I assume here, since he has not mentioned anything else, referring to the same laptop. Maybe the question should be "What are you trying to connect to" for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Windows by default always disables Telnet service because of its high vulnerability. Therefore you must first enable it in Windows Features. [Instructions Here](https://kb.ctera.com/article/how-to-open-a-telnet-session-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-os-16.html)

After that you must allow it in your inbound firewall rules. [Instructions to get to Inbound Rules](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

Port 23 must be allowed during the setup of the port you want to open.

After that, you should be able to telnet into the machine.